# Do powers of logarithm arise naturally in any physical equation?

Tags: soft-question

Everything that we learned in the school maths I've come to use at one time or another. Except one thing. Solving equations like this:

$$
1 + \log_2^2 x = \log_2 8x
$$

"Where do we use this in real life?" Is this an example of an actually useless piece of school maths or have I not come across the real life use yet?

I am not sure why, but raising a logarithm to a power (other than 1 or 0) seems inherently unphysical to me.

Comment: Powers of logarithms are not unphysical at all. For example, they arise when renormalizing physical quantities in quantum field theories, as in equation (40) here: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c6cd/ffae3324bf00a7fac6e3e3c2dbf7fb5391b8.pdf